# Rails docker - Bundle with custom path not able to access gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler

I have a Dockerfile with below main parts:

```
    FROM ruby:2.2.4

# Create user and group
RUN groupadd myapp --gid 6156 && \
    useradd --home /home/myapp --create-home --shell /bin/false --uid 6157 --gid 6156 myapp

# Create and switch to the repo dir
ENV REPO_DIR /home/myapp/repo
RUN mkdir $REPO_DIR
WORKDIR $REPO_DIR


# First install gems
ADD Gemfile      $REPO_DIR
ADD Gemfile.lock $REPO_DIR
RUN mkdir -p /var/bundle &&\
  chown -R myapp:myapp /var/bundle &&\
  mkdir $REPO_DIR/.bundle &&\
  chown -R myapp:myapp $REPO_DIR/.bundle
RUN su -c " cd $REPO_DIR && bundle install --deployment --path /var/bundle" -s /bin/bash -l myapp

 ...
CMD  ["rails","s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

the main parts are

- run as a customer `myapp` user
- `bundle install` with `--deployment` and `--path /var/bundle` arguments

When I do `docker-compose up` , the image is built properly. However, when I run

```
docker-compose run --service-ports api /bin/bash
```

and then,

```
$ bundle check
```

says that all the gems are missing..

```
$ bundle config
```

says

```
Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.
silence_root_warning
Set via BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING: "1"

app_config
Set via BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG: "/usr/local/bundle"

bin
Set via BUNDLE_BIN: "/usr/local/bundle/bin"

path
Set via BUNDLE_PATH: "/usr/local/bundle"
```

There is some problem, as the `BUNDLE_PATH` should be `/var/bundle` in this case.

Obviously, `bundle exec rails` says `rails not found. Please install all missing gems`.

What should I be doing to access the installed gems from `/var/bundle`?

[Bundle install fails in Rails Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411789/bundle-install-fails-in-rails-docker-container) looks similar, but did not help. All my tests are in local.